# What determines if a link is visited?

Tags: html, accessibility, voiceover, screen-readers, visited

I'm having an issue while testing our webapp for accessibility that despite being seemingly very simple, I haven't been able to find a clear answer for on Google.

The issue is that the screen reader (specifically Voice Over in iOS and OSX Safari) reads every internal link in the app as "Visited Link" even before the user has clicked any of them. The links all have the same base (something like http://domain.com/path/index.html#what-the-link-does), so my first instinct is that since these links all point to different hashes on the same file the links are being views as visited because that file has been visited.

However, that's not the desired behavior. We'd like all the links to just be referred to as just "Link" instead. So here are my questions:

1. What determines whether the link is considered visited? Will just visiting the domain cause it? Will visiting a specific file cause it? Or should different hashes of the same file have different visited statuses?
2. Is there any way to control this behavior and prevent the links from being read as visited? Some Aria parameter maybe?

Comment: if you need to mark all of them as unvisited it's possible by using `a:visited` selector , but you can't know which link he visited and which he didn't unless you have js code in your site that copy the link to cookies or database before redirect to it ( as facebook and google are doing now ) , but if the user visit the link from outside your site you wouldn't know

Comment: and by the way saving which links the user visited in your site maybe consider "Violation of privacy" , so if you are doing this you should notify the users of this

Comment: If the user went to  http://example.com/path/index.html than all the links to it will be visited. The hash means nothing other than a location on the page.

Comment: JavaScript alert. Try "reading" a differnet, random page you didn't visit before. What happens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I may have misunderstood the question, but if your links are on `index.html` in your example, can you not replace

```
http://domain.com/path/index.html#what-the-link-does
```

with simply

```
#what-the-link-does
```

The visited logic is probably only looking at the URI without query string / anchor tags being taken into account

Comment: I think you may have pointed me in the right direction. After taking another look at this I noticed that a few of the links were just pointing to `"#"` with click behavior controlled completely by JS. I suspect that if I change the links to `"#a-unique-value"` then they'll be less likely to considered visited.

Answer (score 0):

It's implementation dependent. According to [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#link-pseudo-classes),

> It is possible for style sheet authors to abuse the :link and :visited
>   pseudo-classes to determine which sites a user has visited without the
>   user's consent.
>
> UAs may therefore treat all links as unvisited links, or implement
>   other measures to preserve the user's privacy while rendering visited
>   and unvisited links differently.

The spec only requires `:link` and `:visited` to be mutually exclusive, but doesn't specify how.

Comment: The problem here is that _unvisited_ links are treated as visited links, not the other way round.

Comment: Yeah, that's the issue. There isn't any styling for `:visited`, so it all looks fine. I just want the screen reader to stop reading every link as if it were visited.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue you're having is a misapplication of the anchor tag in regards to accessibility. I'm assuming you are coding a single page application, and every link to a different view is an anchor. You should be using a **button** tag instead with some CSS ninjitsu. There is a fantastic article about this exact thing here:

http://www.karlgroves.com/2013/05/14/links-are-not-buttons-neither-are-divs-and-spans/